# Using bootstrap-notify with Angular 7

Tags: angular, notifications, bootstrap-4, notify

I would like to use `bootstrap-notify` in my Angular 7 application.

To do this, I have installed the `bootstrap-notify` package (and also `@types/bootstrap-notify`).

In my component from where I want to use the notifications I imported the jQuery service like this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

And now called `notify` as described [here](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/#documentation) in the documentation:

```
$.notify({
    // options
    message: 'Hello World' 
},{
    // settings
    type: 'danger'
});
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(28,7): error TS2339: Property 'notify' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.
```

Any idea how to make it work? I couldn't find any Angular (5/6/7) example that is using this package!

Comment: perhaps this might help https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify/issues/185

Comment: Also, consider looking into `ngx-toastr` for non-jquery toasts that will work without importing jquery and jquery types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following.

1) First install type definition for jquery:

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

2) Then in component file, import jquery and notify and use them.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-notify';

$[`notify`](....);
```

3) lastly, you also need to add css file/link to see it's actual styled.

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-alert-message-hqrysq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

sometimes it throws error, but if you add some spaces to the code and save it, it will behave correctly.

Comment: this code is not working. @Abos can you please check it?