# How to use bootstrap-notify in react

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-notify

i want to use http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/ in my react app, i have tried to follow [Using bootstrap-notify with Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236386/using-bootstrap-notify-with-angular-7) but getting error "`$.notify is not a function`" in console

Answer (score 0):

You need the necessary imports:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "bootstrap-notify";
```

You will need to load them using `npm i jquery --save` and `npm i bootstrap-notify --save`. I also had some compiler errors after installing, which I fixed with: ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199001/typeerror-err-invalid-arg-type-the-path-argument-must-be-of-type-string-re))

`npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@3.4.0`